# Swift dealing with Actions and Selectors Issue -

Tags: swift, selector

What gives? The error I keep getting is on the first line for the action argument. I've tried "mapTypeChanged:"....#selector(mapTypeChanged)... and more.. and I keep getting either a yellow or red error. What's up with this?

```
   class viewControllerForMap: UIViewController {

    var mapView : MKMapView!

    override func loadView() {
        mapView = MKMapView()
        self.view = mapView

        let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Standard", "Hybrid", "Satellite"])
        segmentedControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        segmentedControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(segmentedControl)

        segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(mapTypeChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

        func mapTypeChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
            switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
            case 0:
                mapView.mapType = .standard
            case 1:
                mapView.mapType = .hybrid
            case 2:
                mapView.mapType = .satellite
            case _:
                break
            }
        }

        let topConstraint = segmentedControl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 8)
        let leadingConstraint = segmentedControl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor)
        let trailingConstraint = segmentedControl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor)

        topConstraint.isActive = true
        leadingConstraint.isActive = true
        trailingConstraint.isActive = true

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the updated code the problem appears to be that your

```
func mapTypeChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
            switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
            case 0:
                mapView.mapType = .standard
            case 1:
                mapView.mapType = .hybrid
            case 2:
                mapView.mapType = .satellite
            case _:
                break
            }
        }
```

function is currently inside of your other method.

It should look like:

```
    class viewControllerForMap: UIViewController {

        var mapView : MKMapView!

        override func loadView() {
            mapView = MKMapView()
            self.view = mapView

            let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Standard", "Hybrid", "Satellite"])
            segmentedControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
            segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
            segmentedControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            self.view.addSubview(segmentedControl)

            segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(mapTypeChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

            let topConstraint = segmentedControl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 8)
            let leadingConstraint = segmentedControl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor)
            let trailingConstraint = segmentedControl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor)

            topConstraint.isActive = true
            leadingConstraint.isActive = true
            trailingConstraint.isActive = true

        }

func mapTypeChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
                switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
                case 0:
                    mapView.mapType = .standard
                case 1:
                    mapView.mapType = .hybrid
                case 2:
                    mapView.mapType = .satellite
                case _:
                    break
                }
            }

    }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't think the break statements are needed. Swift has never needed those, unless you coded a default that could (but shouldn't) be reached.

Comment: Whoops yea, back to ObjC days for a moment there.  Good catch.  Editing.

Comment: Sorry but still get an error: "Use of unresolved identifier 'mapTypeChanged'

Comment: It's a little difficult to tell but based on what you posted here it looks as though your segmentedControl.addTarget line is not inside of a function.  Is that true? Would you be able to show more code?

Comment: I have updated the code for you. I am getting circular errors. I change one thing, another error with a different excuse pops up on the same line of code.

Comment: Looks like your function is inside of your function.  You need to move that out.

Comment: What's the problem with a function inside of a function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130062/discussion-between-user7024499-and-steve).